# Missing permissions required by MobileAds.initialize?

Tags: java, android

I got a warning in Android Studio:

Missing permissions required by MobileAds.initialize...

in the following Java code.

```
MobileAds.initialize(this,"ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713");
AdView mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

But build is successfully done.

Why does this occur?

Comment: You need two permissions: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/> and you also need to include following namespace code in the Layout tag : xmlns:ads="schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"

Comment: Thank you for your comment!  But I've already added that. There is still the warning...why?

Comment: are using this one -     implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.0.0'

Comment: Yes,it's already been included. By the way, I  did invalidate caches and restart before. the warning has  occured since that time...does this action relate to this problem?

Comment: Oh! I see the reason why the warning occur! Top level gradle file was absurd without noticing! But why does this occur...?  "invalidate caches and restart" caused this...?